# Jhipster and Kafka 2.x well supported?

Tags: apache-kafka, jhipster

Jhipster 5.7 generates a kafka.yml file referencing kafka 1.0.0.
Is Kafka 2.x well supported (and already tested) by jhipster. If yes, is the move to kafka 2.x planned ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks more like a feature request to post on github

Comment: Thans. I post it on github. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9147